# C# Best way to check DateTime

Tags: c#

I feel like I've been in a bad habbit for years and I just want to kick myself. A lot of my apps are time based, meaning I want to start something after 9:30.  Below is the code I use all the time and I feel as if there should be a better way.

```
static bool Run()
{
    return (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 9 && DateTime.Now.Minute > 30) && DateTime.Now.Hour < 16;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the new `TimeOnly` to and store the start- and end-time since it will not change:

```
private static readonly TimeOnly RunTimeStart = new TimeOnly(9, 30);
private static readonly TimeOnly RunTimeEnd = new TimeOnly(16, 00);

static bool Run()
{
    TimeOnly now = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    return now >= RunTimeStart && now <= RunTimeEnd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to encapsulate the logic related to checking the current time within a separate method, making it clear and reusable.

Here is the approach:

```
static bool IsTimeWithinRange(int startHour, int startMinute, int endHour)
{
    TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(startHour, startMinute, 0);
    TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(endHour, 0, 0);

    return currentTime >= startTime && currentTime < endTime;
}

static bool Run()
{
    return IsTimeWithinRange(9, 30, 16);
}
```

By organizing the code in this way, you make it easier to understand the intent of each method and promote code reusability. Additionally, if you ever need to change the time range in the future, you can do so by simply updating the parameters of `IsTimeWithinRange` without modifying the `Run` method.

Comment: It would be better to use either my NodaTime project and a `LocalTime`, or a `TimeOnly` from .NET 6+. No need to keep multiple integers around for something which is fundamentally a single value.

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks for the suggestions, will update it!